# Rails i18n linking issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

So within `config/locales/`, a file `en.yml` exists containing, in part:

```
en:
  company:
    street: 'x'
```

with my view (initially an erb temp) I am calling `<%= t(company.street) %>` however I am receiving the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `company' for #<#<Class:0x007fbbf1544de0>:0x007fbbf121b448>
```

Thoughts as to where I may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`company.street` should be a string, so you have to add missing quotation marks to it `t('company.street')`